# Set Zoom Default to 125% Excel 2011 on OS X

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2011

I don't like smal fonts. Therefore I would like to have a default zoom level of 125% for all spread sheets in Excel 2011 on OS X Lion. Is there a way to tell Excel to open all spread sheets with a zoom level of 125%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/08/zoom-to-125-percent-excel-2011-default-workbook/) explains how to do it. In short, you have to creare a new template.

Answer (score 0):

I did this, it works for new workbooks

```
Sub auto_open()
'
' SetDefaultZoomto125 Macro
' sets default zoom to 125% on start up of XL

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 125
End Sub
```

hope it helps you.